# Group consecutive elements of specific value in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have a list of numbers in haskell and I want to perform the following transformation:

- When an element is not equal to 1, just **append this element** on the new list
- When an element is equal to 1 append to the list **a sublist which contains all the consecutive 1s** and then proceed with the next character that is not equal to 1

To make the requirement clear I am posting an **example**:

```
Input: [1,2,3,1,1,1,2,3,4,2,1]

Expected Output: [[1] , 2 , 3 , [1,1,1] , 2 , 3 , 4 , 2 , [1]]
```

Important Notice: The elements that are not equal to 1 are not added in a sublist

I have found some workarounds to make it work, but I need to find an elegant solution that does not traverse the elements of the list more than once.

Any ideas?

Comment: The expected output is *not* possible in Haskell. In Haskell, lists are *homogenous*: all elements have the *same* type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a [group](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:group) function

```
>> import Data.List
>> group [1,2,3,1,1,1,2,3,4,2,1]
>> [[1],[2],[3],[1,1,1],[2],[3],[4],[2],[1]]
```

note that every item is a list because values in list should have the same type. Thats why your example `[[1], 2, ..]` is impossible in Haskell

---

If you want to form groups of **1s** and the rest then you could use [groupBy](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:groupBy)

```
>> import Data.List
>> groupBy (\a -> \b -> a == b && a == 1 || a /= 1 && b /= 1) [1,2,3,1,1,1,2,3,4,2,1]
>> [[1],[2,3],[1,1,1],[2,3,4,2],[1]]
```

Comment: I think he wants to group only 1s and leave the others ungrouped, so `groupBy (\a b -> a == 1 && b ==1) [...]` should work.

Comment: @Alex -- The posted answer groups non-1s together (`...,[2,3,4,2],...`).  My proposed answer keeps them as singletons (`...,[2],[3],[4],[2],...`).